# OpenCart 2.3.0.2 Can not save custom module settings

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I have this trouble on admin part of My module. My OpenCart version: 2.3.0.2. 
Where is the problem ?

**admin/controller/extension/module/mymodule.php**

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleMyModule extends Controller {
private $error = array();

public function index() {
    $this->load->language('extension/module/mymodule');
    $this->load->model('setting/setting');
    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
        $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('mymodule', $this->request->post);
        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=module', true));
    }

    $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
    $data['text_edit'] = $this->language->get('text_edit');
    $data['entry_text'] = $this->language->get('entry_text');

    $data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
    $data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');

    if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
        $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
    } else {
        $data['error_warning'] = '';
    }

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)
    );
    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_extension'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=module', true)
    );
    if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module/mymodule', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)
        );
    } else {
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module/mymodule', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&module_id=' . $this->request->get['module_id'], true)
        );
    }

    $data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/module/mymodule', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true);

    $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=module', true);

    if (isset($this->request->post['text_example'])) {
        $data['text_example'] = $this->request->post['text_example'];
    } else {
        $data['text_example'] = $this->config->get('text_example');
    }

    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/mymodule', $data));
}

protected function validate() {
    if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'extension/module/mymodule')) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    }

    return !$this->error;
}
}
```

**admin/view/template/extension/module/mymodule.tpl**

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<div id="content">
<div class="page-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="submit" form="form-mymodule" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
            <a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_cancel; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a>
        </div>
        <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error_warning; ?>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo $text_edit; ?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-mymodule" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-text-example"><?php echo $entry_text; ?></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" name="text_example" value="<?php echo $text_example; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $text_example; ?>" id="input-text-example" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**admin/language/en-gb/extension/module/mymodule.php**

```
<?php
// Heading
$_['heading_title']    = 'My Module';

// Text
$_['text_extension']   = 'Extensions';
$_['text_success']     = 'Success: You have modified My module!';
$_['text_edit']        = 'Edit My Module';

// Entry
$_['entry_text']     = 'text';

// Error
$_['error_permission'] = 'Warning: You do not have permission to modify My module!';
```

**error.log = empty.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in your naming convention. You should use `modulename_input` for your input field in form. You can do this way.

1.Change the code in your controller

```
if (isset($this->request->post['mymodule_text_example'])) {
        $data['text_example'] = $this->request->post['mymodule_text_example'];
    } else {
        $data['text_example'] = $this->config->get('mymodule_text_example');
}
```

2.And in your related view file

```
<input type="text" name="mymodule_text_example" value="<?php echo $text_example; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $text_example; ?>" id="input-text-example" class="form-control" />
```

Hope it will work perfectly. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

**mymodule.php**

```
if (isset($this->request->post['mymodule_text_example'])) {
        $data['mymodule_text_example'] = $this->request->post['mymodule_text_example'];
    } else {
        $data['mymodule_text_example'] = $this->config->get('mymodule_text_example');
    }
```

**mymodule.tpl**

```
<input type="text" name="mymodule_text_example" value="<?php echo $mymodule_text_example; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $mymodule_text_example; ?>" id="input-text-example" class="form-control" />
```